# How to share a YouTube video on Facebook and have it work on iPad?

Tags: facebook, html, video, youtube

I'm creating a site which allows the user to watch videos. The videos are hosted on YouTube and embedded into our site. We would the user to be able to share our site on Facebook and have the video play inline on the Facebook wall.

We've gotten this to work using Open Graph tags, but there is one problem: when using Facebook through the iOS app or via iOS Safari, an error message comes up saying the playback is not supported since it requires Adobe Flash. Note that when you share a YouTube.com URL, there is an automatic fallback to HTML5 and the video will play on the wall.

How can I get my video to play on the wall? Or at least, how can I make the video link point to our site instead of triggering the error message?

See here for an example of our site: http://m.gad.dk/at-overleve-med-en-alkoholiker/film/

Thanks.

Comment: would like to know too. Have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, best I could do was to provide the site URL -- it now opens that in the browser when pressing the link in the Facebook app. Using the mobile site still doesn't work, though. Let me know if you solve it!

Comment: I actually just found something. I didn't test it yet but take a look at [this](http://blog.kaltura.org/facebook-now-require-html5-and-fallback-in-open-graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this posts? That might be helpful to you.

1. [iPhone App how to post Youtube video link using facebook graph Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261000/iphone-app-how-to-post-youtube-video-link-using-facebook-graph-api)
2. [Posting an embedded video link using the Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227607/posting-an-embedded-video-link-using-the-facebook-graph-api)
3. [How can I post a video, via Facebook's Connect API, to my Facebook profile page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106617/how-can-i-post-a-video-via-facebooks-connect-api-to-my-facebook-profile-page)